# Keep leading zeros when converted from long to string

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I am converting a `long` to a `String` using `String.format()`. It works fine when numbers >0 are passed, but when I add leading zeros to the number, I get a different number in output. My requirement is to show user with leading zeros when leading zeros are passed. Please advise.

```
public class CreateContractNumber {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long account = 0000123;
    long schedule = 001;
    CreateContractNumber ccn = new CreateContractNumber();
    System.out.println("CONTRACT #: "+ccn.createContNbr(account, schedule));
  }

  private String createContNbr(long account, long schedule) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("%07d", account);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(String.format("%03d", schedule);
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Actual Output: 
CONTRACT #: 0000083-001

Expected Output:
CONTRACT #: 0000123-001

Comment: A type like `long` does not know anything like *leading zeros*. Actually Java is interpreting anything with leading `0` as **octal number** (a number not in decimal but in octal format). Stuff like leading zeros is display/formatting only and therefore should be kept in Formatter classes tor strings only. So you should make your computations on `long` and after that apply Formatter patterns to display it with appropriate amount of leading zeros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`long account = 0000123;` is an octal number. 0123 oct is 83 dec which makes your output correct. If you need 123 dec just write `long account = 123;` as leading zeros have no effect on the value stored in `long`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 123 is what the number should look like.